# Submit Spark job through IntelliJ on YARN

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I'm trying to make applications in Spark in IntelliJ and push the same into YARN. By now I was reading about how to push *jars* through ***spark-submit*** but I really want to avoid working in terminal.

Can you suggest me what to set, how to set or even better, where to work with Spark aplications and be able to debug them like I can in IntelliJ

I'm using Ambari, and I setted there YARN and Spark cluster. Lets say that this is IP of mine *ResourceManager* is ***bigdata5.local:8050***.

How to set `setMaster` method, 
`spark.setMaster("spark://bigdata5.local:8050")` maybe? Because like that I'm getting error about

`INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/06/07 14:06:50 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://localhost:4040
17/06/07 14:06:50 INFO AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://bigdata5.local:8050...
17/06/07 14:06:50 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 1 requests outstanding when connection from bigdata5.local:8050 is closed`

Please lead me with best practices :)

*UPDATE 1:*

Also after a while, I'm getting as add-on this error:

`java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`